# communicate with rsync daemon without sockets

Tags: rsync, daemon

According to the manpage, `rsync --daemon` will either:

- try to communicate using the rsync protocol using stdin/out, if it detects that the stdin/out are a socket,
- open a TCP socket for listening and use it to expose the rsync protocol endpoint, otherwise.

Is it possible to force `rsync` to the first behavior without connecting sockets to its stdin/out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, apparently I need to pass the undocumented-on-purpose `--server` option as the first parameter to `rsync`:

```
liori:~% rsync --server --daemon --config <(printf "") .
@RSYNCD: 31.0
hi
@ERROR: protocol startup error
liori:~%
```

(This `hi` in the middle is me trying to greet the daemon properly. Apparently the daemon didn't like it…)

Notes:

- I was too lazy to create a proper `rsyncd.conf` file, so I'm creating an ad-hoc one with `--config <(printf "")`. Otherwise `rsync` would log `rsync: unable to open config file "rsyncd.conf": No such file or directory` to the syslog.
- The dot at the end of the command line seems important (otherwise rsync prints `rsync error: syntax or usage error` to the syslog), but I have no idea what is it for.